# Convert Object to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, converting

```
public static DateTime ObjectToDateTime(object o, DateTime defaultValue)
{            
    if (o == null) return defaultValue;

    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(o.ToString(), out dt))
        return dt;
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

The code feels too wordy and smells bad.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You could get rid of the "else" (because in the true case it has already returned), but that's not much of an improvement.  Other than that, this looks pretty optimal (clarity-wise) to me.

Comment: return o as DateTime ?? defaultValue;

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type and thus could not be used with the `as` operator nor set to `null`.  That would be invalid code.

Comment: As @Jeff Mercado says, you cannot use a DateTime object with the `as` keyword. A failed conversion cannot be set to null. However, if you use a `DateTime?` (nullable DateTime) instead, your code would work.

Comment: I must add that if you use `ToString()` on an object you might be losing some information depending on the DateTime format (for example the milliseconds part). I.e. `o.ToString() = "19/06/2017 14:17:04"` but `((DateTime)o).ToString("o") = 2017-06-19T14:17:04.0393053+02:00`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On the offhand chance that your object is *already* a `DateTime`, you're performing unnecessary conversions to and from strings.

```
 if (o is DateTime)
     return (DateTime)o;
```

This also strikes me as something you might be doing for a database item, for example. In which case, I'd encourage you to know and trust your data types and then use existing methods of retrieval.

For example, if you have a `DataTable` with a column `CreatedDate`, you should know it's a date, what you might not know is if it has a value if the column is nullable at the database. That's fine, you can handle that in code.

```
 var createdDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("CreatedDate");
```

There we go, a `DateTime?`, no coding of a conversion necessary. You can even specify a default and type if to `DateTime`

```
 var createdDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("CreatedDate").GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
 var createdDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("CreatedDate") ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Correct, I usually use this notation for the same purpose: `if (o is DateTime result) return result;`

Answer (score 3):

I like @ChaosPandion's solution however I find the following a bit quicker to read.

```
public static DateTime ObjectToDateTime(object o, DateTime defaultValue)
{    
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParse((o ?? "").ToString(), out result)) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

If you prefer the explicit null check, modify the if statement a bit...

```
    if (o != null && DateTime.TryParse(o.ToString(), out result)) {
```

Coming from a language without the ?? operator, I find this even easier to quickly read and understand the intent of however I recognize that is probably just because I'm not used to reading ??.

Answer (score 3):

*Side note*

Since C# 7 it is now possible to declare the variables within the *is* clause which can come handy. For example

```
        if (o1 is DateTime startDate &&
            o2 is DateTime endDate &&
            startDate > endDate)
            return true;
```

Comment: And to match OP code you may also show it with `out var dt` in `TryParse() `

Answer (score 1):

The big problem I see here is your method name. I'd expect `ObjectToDateTime` to parse my object to a `DateTime` but that's not exactly what happens, right? Your method tries to parse the input and returns a default value if this doesn't work. Your method name should reflect that sentence. I'd call it `ParseDateTimeOrDefault` or something like that. It kind of follows the `IEnumerable.SingleOrDefault` trend.

Now, there's another problem. Your intention seems to be to cast an `object` to a `DateTime`, but you actually parse the `ToString()` of the object.

The point is, as a user of your method, I'd expect this to return the default value :

```
DateTime someDateTime; /*= Unimportant*/
dt = DateTime.Now;
ObjectToDateTime(dt.ToString(), someDateTime);
```

Why? Because the `object` I pass as a parameter isn't a `DateTime`, it's a `string`. You *parse* a string, if it doesn't work, you return a value. That's your method.

The question is : In your application, is there a scenario where you don't know if you'll either receive a `string` or a `DateTime`? Because that seems like a design flaw in my opinion.